# How to retrieve opportunities and their partners via SOQL?

Tags: soql, query

There's a report type that I can select "Opportunities with Partners".

[image]

When created, it shows Opportunity, Partner, and Account information

In SF there are two objects to represent this relationship: **Partner** and **OpportunityPartner**.

How can I get the same result of "Opportunities with Partners" via SOQL"?

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT 
    Opportunity.Name, 
    Opportunity.Account.Name

FROM 
    Opportunity
WHERE
    Opportunity.AccountId <> null AND
    Opportunity.Id IN (SELECT OpportunityId FROM Partner )
```

This gets the opportunities with partners, but there's something missing to retrieve the partner's name for each Opportunity

Comment: so, what have you tried?  please use [edit]

Comment: Did you search for the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunitypartner.htm)?

Comment: I have added the query that I tried

Comment: What are you seeing? What are you expecting to see?

Comment: What Am I expecting to See? Create a new report and select "Opportunities with Partners". That's it. That result via SOQL. I've got a solution. take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching for a long time, I found people looking via Apex, SOQL inside loops and so on. But I've got a solution. It may be useful to others.

```
SELECT 
    Opportunity.Name, 
    Opportunity.Account.Name,
    (Select AccountTo.Name FROM OpportunityPartnersFrom)
FROM 
    Opportunity
WHERE
    Opportunity.AccountId <> null AND
    Opportunity.Id IN (SELECT OpportunityId FROM Partner )
```

***"(Select AccountTo.Name FROM OpportunityPartnersFrom)"*** retrieves an object. You will have to process it.

Another and easier way is by retrieving from AccountPartner

```
SELECT  
    OpportunityId,
    Opportunity.Name,
    AccountFromId, 
    AccountFrom.Name, 
    AccountToId, 
    AccountTo.Name, 
    IsPrimary,
    Role 
FROM 
    AccountPartner
```